# Why do I have to create a new Scanner? when creating a driver

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As you can see this is a fragment of a code that I am working on. My question is why do I have to create a new scanner to be able to input? why can't I just use `stdIn.nextLine();` instead? If you can include some references I will really appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Week6{

    public static void main(String[]args){
    Horse horse1;
    Horse horse2;
    Horse horse3;
    String name;
    int age;
    double height;
    String color;
    boolean pureBlood;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    horse1 = new Horse(); // creation of Horse1
    horse2 = new Horse(); // creation of horse2
    horse3 = new Horse(); // creation of horse3

    System.out.print("Enter the name of Horse1: ");
    name = in.nextLine();

    horse1.setName(name); //setting name for horse1

    System.out.println(horse1.getName());



    } // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: Accept jondiaz's answer as his answer is perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use stdIn, because neither java has that object nor you have created. 
When you write `myString.nextline()` you are calling the object myString (all strings are objects, ex.: String myString = **new** String("Hello World!")), but if you call stdIn it will display an error.

I haven't found any java library which you can use stdIn, but stdIn is for PHP, Python and C, so maybe you have got confused because of this.

Answer (score 4):

Check the javadoc for `java.lang.System`, `java.io.InputStream` and `java.io.Scanner`.

`System.in` is an `InputStream`. As such, you can use the `InputStream` methods to access data from it, which are quite basic.

When you create the new `Scanner`, you are wrapping the `InputStream` in a different class, that offers more advanced / comfortable methods like `readLine` or `nextLine` which just are not available in the definition of `InputStream`.

If it helps visualizing what I mean, think that your `Scanner` variable may have any different name so there is no direct relationship due to that. In short, you are not creating "another" `Scanner` because in your code there is only one `Scanner` instance (the one you create).

Answer (score 1):

We are using Scanner class to get input from user.We first create an object of Scanner class and then we use the methods of Scanner class.Scanner class is present in java.util package so we import this package in our program
for ex :

> Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

Following methods of Scanner class are used

1) nextInt to input an integer

2) nextFloat to input a float

3) nextLine to input a string

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class GetInputFromUser
{
public static void main(String args[])
 {
  int a;
  float b;
  String s;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string");
  s = in.nextLine();
  System.out.println("You entered string "+s);

  System.out.println("Enter an integer");
  a = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("You entered integer "+a);

  System.out.println("Enter a float");
  b = in.nextFloat();
  System.out.println("You entered float "+b);   
 }
}
```

Hope! This helps u...

Comment: This is not the answer at all .